# My simple turing machine

Tags: language-agnostic, turing-machines

I'm trying to understand and implement the simplest turing machine and would like feedback if I'm making sense.

We have a infinite tape (lets say an array called T with pointer at 0 at the start) and instruction table:

```
( S , R , W , D , N )

S->STEP (Start at step 1)
R->READ (0 or 1)
W->WRITE (0 or 1)
D->DIRECTION (0=LEFT 1=RIGHT)
N->NEXTSTEP (Non existing step is HALT)
```

My understanding is that a 3-state 2-symbol is the simplest machine. 3-state i don't understand. 2-symbol because we use 0 and 1 for READ/WRITE.

For example:

```
(1,0,1,1,2)
(1,1,0,1,2)
```

Starting at step 1, if Read is 0 then { Write 1, Move Right) else {Write 0, Move Right) and then go to step 2 - which does not exist which halts program.

What does 3-state mean? Does this machine pass as turing machine? Can we simplify more?

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion might come from your use of "steps" instead of "states". You can think of a machine's state as the value it has in its memory (although as a previous poster noted, some people also take a machine's state to include the contents of the tape -- however, I don't think that definition is relevant to your question). It's possible that this change in terminology might be at the heart of your confusion. Let me explain what I think it is you're thinking. :)

You gave lists of five numbers -- for example, (1,0,1,1,2). As you correctly state, this should be interpreted (reading from left to right) as "If the machine is in state 1 AND the current square contains a 0, print a 1, move right, and change to state 2." However, your use of the word "step" seems to suggest that that "step 2" must be followed by "step 3", etc., when in reality a Turing machine can go back and forth between states (and of course, there can only be finitely many possible states).

So to answer your questions:

- Turing machines keep track of "states" not "steps";
- What you've described is a legitimate Turing machine;
- A simpler (albeit otherwise uninteresting) Turing machine would be one that starts in the HALT state.

Edits: Grammar, Formatting, and removed a needless description of Turing machines.

**Response to comment**:
Correct me if I'm misinterpreting your comment, but I did not mean to suggest a Turing machine could be in more than one state at a time, only that the number of possible states can be any finite number. For example, for a 3-state machine, you might label the possible states A, B, and C. (In the example you provided, you labeled the two possible states as '1' and '2') At any given time, exactly one of those values (states) would be in the machine's memory. We would say, "the machine is in state A" or "the machine is in state B", etc. (Your machine starts in state '1' and terminates after it enters state '2').

Also, it's no longer clear to me what you mean by a "simpler/est" machine. The smallest known Universal Turing machine (i.e., a Turing machine that can simulate another Turing machine, given an appropriate tape) requires 2 states and 5 symbols (see [the relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_Machine#Smallest_machines)).

On the other hand, if you're looking for something simpler than a Turing machine with the same computation power, [Post-Turing machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%E2%80%93Turing_machine) might be of interest.

Comment: NEXTSTEP does not necessarily mean STEP+1. Using the word 'STATE' instead of 'STEP' here would not make more sense since there can be 2 defined which goes against the meaning of the word 'STATE'. Maybe there is a better word than both STEP and STATE. And yes, when I say simpler I mean a simpler definition that still can be programmed to do any computation.

Comment: @Yehonatan: I've updated my answer in response to your comment. I'm not entirely sure I understand you correctly, though; if I'm still not adequately addressing your questions, I would appreciate clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the concept of state is basically the same as in [Finite State Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). If I recall, you need a separate termination state, to which the turing machine can transition after it has finished running the program. As for why 3 states I'd guess that the other two states are for intialisation and execution respectively.

Unfortunately none of that is guaranteed to be correct, but I thought I'd post my thoughts anyway since the question was unanswered for 5 hours. I suspect if you were to re-ask this question on cstheory.stackexchange.com you might get a better/more definative answer.

Comment: So whats the difference between FSM and TM?

Comment: @Yehonatan: An FSM has no tape. You feed an FSM input (a stream of ones and zeroes, for example), but this stream is not like a tape, since the FSM cannot rewind or modify it.

Answer (score 0):

"State" in the context of Turing machines should be clarified as to which is being described: (i) the current instruction, or (ii) the list of symbols on the tape together with the current instruction, or (iii) the list of symbols on the tape together with the current instruction placed to the left of the scanned symbol or to the right of the scanned symbol. [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#The_.22state.22)